# Completely disable autosave in vimwiki when switching links and buffers

Tags: lua, markdown, neovim, vimwiki

On my init.lua file with set nohidden and with autowriteall = 0 my buffers are not being autosaved when I switch links within vimwki, and I want that, I don't want to save edited buffers when I switch to the next link, within vimwiki, not unless I type :w But every time I open a new link on vimwiki, a new tab is being opened. How do I disable that?